# Calling iframe with a password protected page - can i hide my credentials?

Tags: html, authentication, iframe, password-encryption

I was just wondering if i can hide my creds on the iframe, as I am calling a server side password protected page inside the iframe

```
<iframe src="http://username:password@domain.com/index.php">
   <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can, if it's an external site and their security is any good, you usually get given a security key tied to your company.  If it is on your own site, you could store the credentials in a session and use that instead of a querystring

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is to create 2 progs, the 2nd would display the iframe.

1. create session
2. display iframe (if user and password are correct)

iframegoto.php which calls iframedisp.php which in turn displays the iframe.

**iframegoto.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['userName'] = 'userName';
$_SESSION['passwprd'] = 'passwprd';
header('Location: http://YourURL/iframedisplay.php');
?>
```

**iframedisplay.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['userName']) and 
$_SESSION['passwprd']=="passwprd" and $_SESSION['userName']=="userName")
{
echo "Welcome : ".$_SESSION['userName'];
echo "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' frameborder='0' src='http://whatever.com'></iframe>"; 
}
else echo "You are not Authorised";
?>
```

Comment: This simple does not work, there is no mechanism for passing the credentials to the server.